sentence patterns for counters
A number of sources say that there are two patterns in which counters are used.

Numeral + Counter + の + Noun
Noun + Particle + Numeral + Counter

I’ve just come across:

犬は四本足である

(although I think I’ve seen the pattern on other occasions).
How is this pattern best explained? Is it simply casual usage? Is it best considered as a 3rd pattern?

Hint: I've just removed the spaces from your sentence.

四本足 is a noun / no-adjective. But even if we consider 本足 to be a counter, then that example sentence would match pattern 2. What is it that you do not understand?

@Arfrever I was trying to hint at 四本足 being a noun (probably too subtle), but I don't understand how you see this as matching pattern 2. If anything it looks more like pattern one with an omitted の. I think for option 2 the OP was expecting something like 犬は足が四本である.

@user3856370 There are matches for e.g. "六本足" "蜘蛛", "八本足" "虫", so probably it makes sense to consider 本足 to be a counter... Anyway numeral+counter can be used alone without additional noun.

@Arfrever - I wonder which part of 一つ目 and 三つ目 would be considered the counter for "N-eyed" monsters. つ目?

@Arfrever: Thanks for responding. I didn’t understand that 四本足 was a noun. Nor had I considered that 本足 could be a counter (I was locked into the assumption that all counters were single-character).

user3856370: Your assumption was correct

@justerman Article Japanese counter word lists few multi-kanji counters like 時間, 箇月, 段落, 学級, 拍子, 箇国, 種類, 通話.

@aguijonazo Jokes aside, what would be natural and scientific-sounding translation of "This spider is eight-eyed animal."? (Most spiders have 8 eyes, but some have 6 or less.) (I understand that suffix 〜目 turns counter into adjectival construction, so N-つ目 normally means "N-th", e.g. 一つ目 = "first", 二つ目 = "second", 三つ目 = "third", 四つ目 = "fourth", 八つ目 = "eighth".)

@Arfrever - There's an animal called ヤツメウナギ although seven of those "eyes" are not really eyes. If Wikipedia is correct, it seems to be called 七鰓鰻 in Chinese.

@Arfrever: Thank you again. Considering, for example, the first of the multi-kanji “counters” that you cite: would it not be best for me to consider 時間 as a noun? If the following sentence, quoted from jisho, is typical, it is not accompanied by another noun, nor does the pattern conform to either of the counter patterns I listed above: ３時間彼は勉強している

@justerman For all counters, and not just 時間, usage of の particle in Numeral+Counter+の+CountedNoun means that Numeral+Counter itself is some special noun. [間]{かん} is a suffix, which can be used with all time-related counters to change meaning from point in datetime to duration of time. E.g. 十日 = "day 10 (e.g. in given month)", 十分 = "minute 10 (e.g. in given hour)", 十秒 = "second 10 (e.g. in given minute)", 十日間 = "10 days", 十分間 = "10 minutes", 十秒間 = "10 seconds".

@justerman Some nouns can be used adverbially without additional particles. This is not limited to Numeral+Counter(with 間), but it seems to mostly happen with generally time-related nouns. E.g. 昨日, 今日, 明日, and also ...時間 in your example sentence. See also this.

@Arfrever: thank you

You can think 四本足 is a fixed noun (or no-adjective) meaning "quadrupedal", or you can think of 本足 as a counter on its own. Either way, it has little to do with how you usually count the number of apples or pencils in an ordinary sentence. To express "Dogs have four legs" (rather than "Dogs are quadrupedal") as an ordinary sentence, you can say either of these:

犬には足が4本ある。
犬には4本の足がある。

(To be precise, I think 四本足 is not as technical-sounding as "quadrupedal", but it's still a fixed compound.)
There are a few fixed terms that look like 四本足, including 一本槍, 二人羽織, 三羽烏 and 五人囃子. But these are essentially to be memorized as compound words, and they are not common enough to be rightfully called a "3rd pattern".

"four-legged" as in "dogs are our four-legged friends" would be an informal translation of 四本足.

Thanks for responding. I hadn’t considered that 四本足 could be a noun. You’ve also helped me understand structures such as 二週間
